# How to upgrade application for 64 bit support for ZBarSDK

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit, zbar-sdk, iphone-64bit

I have developed an application using ZBarSDK for Barcode. It is working fine with 32 bit support, but while I am going to upgrade it to 64 bit, it is giving linker error. Is there any tutorial or way to find out the solution ? Below are the warnings, with linker error.

> duplicate symbol in:
>       projectpath/arm64/main.o
>
> projectpath/arm64/AppDelegate.o
>
> duplicate symbol in:
>       projectpath/arm64/main.o
>
> projectpath/arm64/ViewController.o
>
> etc...

This kind of warnings and linker error is there for every controller. I konw, this kind of warning comes when there are similar named class are twice or more time in source code, but if I remove 64 bit it is working fine. How to get rid of this kind of linker error.

Comment: I do have zBarSDK for 32 and 64 bits support. I can send you if you need it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the command to merge two or more libraries, I have tried for simulator and device library. After failure, my Sr. helped me and created this attached library.

This SDK I have used before 2 years to support 64bit in my application and was working fine. Not sure about any new changes made by ZBARSDK Team

I have uploaded my SDK at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zhbqsa0heuputlk/AAC1kDkJBxgybtwi7lnmZ9lra?dl=0

You can try this sdk.
Thanks

Comment: This deserves a better answer than "check this broken dropbox link".